# Expected number of weighted dice rolls to achieve a certain outcome

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice, multinomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Lets assume we have a weighted dice roll with sides $ \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$ given $p(i)= p_i $ and $\sum_{i=1}^6 p_i=1$ for some $p_i \in \left(0,1\right)$. Denote by $X_i^{(t)}$ the random variables that are $1$ if event $i$ occured on the $t$-th roll and $0$ if not, for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Let further $S_i^{(t)} = \sum_{k=1}^t X_i^{(k)}$ be the number of times that outcome $i$ occured after $t$ rolls.

Now i want to roll that dice until $1,2,3$ appear a certain number of times without regards to the order, so for example the outcome that $1$ occured $100$ times, $2$ occured $200$ times and $3$ occured $150$ times, more precisely
\begin{equation} Y := \min\lbrace t > 0 \space | \space S_{1}^{(t)} \geq 100, S_{2}^{(t)} \geq 200 , S_{3}^{(t)} \geq 150 \rbrace . \end{equation}

I am interested in the expected number of rolls for that to happen so $E[Y]$. I would like to have a theoretical expression at the end but I also want to calculate it directly or at least approximate it to a certain degree.

My attempt was to look at the $P(Y = t)$, which I broke down recursively and I ended up with a mess of a formula, which theoretically gives me a way to calculate it iteratively for each $t$ but I ended up realizing that especially for large $t$ calculating the faculties $t!$, which appeared in my formula over and over would be unfeasible.

I know that $X_i^{t}$ are Bernoulli distributed, so i tried to consider an elegant way to maybe boil down the expectation of $Y$ to some formula depending on the expectations of $X_i^{t}$, which  I can calculate but I was not really successful yet. I feel like I am missing something obvious that brings about an elegant solution.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Edit: I have now thought of maybe modeling the problem as a markov chain with absorbance state $(0,100,200,150)$, the involving matrices however would be very tedious to calculate, so it does not really solve the problem for now.

Comment: If using a computer is ok, you need to calculate only $100\cdot 200 \cdot 150 < 10^7$ numbers (of form "how long does it take to finish from $i$ ones, $j$ twos and $k$ threes"), which should not be hard. For quick-and-dirty estimation, you need in average 1200 trials to get 200 twos, and by that time you should already have at least $200 - 3\cdot \sqrt{500/3} > 150$ threes with probability about 0.998, so this extra requirements shouldn't affect the estimation too much.

Comment: Hey, yes thats true but im specifically more interested in generalizing this even further and just wanted to give a "simple" example to grasp an idea on how to proceed. On a side note the example I actually want to calculate is basically a 19-sided die with similar number of occurances(between 100-150 of 18 of the 19 sides) and here the numbers get big really quickly, so I was wondering if theres a way to make a compact calculation/sophisticated estimation somehow. Still thanks for your answer, I didn't really try to make a crude estimate first and maybe refine it more.